# How to integrate SimpleGUI with Python 2.7 and 3.0 shell

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, codeskulptor

I am  learning Python from Coursera. In this course they use **SimpleGUI** module on [CodeSkulptor](http://www.codeskulptor.org/). Can anyone tell me how to integrate SimpleGUI with python 2.7 and 3.0 shell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the coursera forums by Darren Gallagher

> From the CodeSkulptor Documentation:
>
> http://www.codeskulptor.org/docs.html
>
> "... implements a subset of Python 2.6...CodeSkulptor's Python is not a subset in one respect...Implemented on top of JavaScript..."
>
> I don't think that CodeSkulptor / SimpleGUI is a Python Module, as we know it. It is written on top of Javascript to allow the user output to their web browser, as opposed to their desktop and/or interpreter window.
>
> The module I have found / used in Python that is most similar to SimpleGUI is Pygame - in both syntax and display. It requires a little more to get a project 'running' but is definitely worth investing time in. I'm sure what we will learn in the coming weeks with SimpleGUI will be very transferable.

The full thread can be found here
[Can the staff give us the SIMPLEGUI module?](https://class.coursera.org/interactivepython-002/forum/thread?thread_id=1029&post_id=5512#post-5512)
(**Note need to be enrolled to the course to view the link**)

---

**A python package called SimpleGUICS2Pygame has since been created to run CodeSkulptor code using Pygame,
I haven't tried it myself yet but it can be found** [**here**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleGUICS2Pygame/)

Answer (score 17):

You can just use SimpleGUITk (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleGUITk) which implements a Tk version of simplegui.

To use your CodeSkulptor code in the desktop, you just need to replace

```
import simplegui
```

with

```
import simpleguitk as simplegui
```

and that's it, your program made for CodeSkulptor code should work on the desktop.

Comment: Note that SimpleGUITk installs pygame. Pygame is not supported for Python 3.3. I recommend that you use Python 2.7.x (2.7.5).

Comment: But In my case its not supporting images and sound.......what should i do to run my Asteroid program in terminal?

Answer (score 15):

You can use my

[image]
**SimpleGUICS2Pygame** package.

Objectively, this is the best solution :-)

**The package implement *simplegui*, *codeskulptor*, *numeric* and *simpleplot* modules.**

**If** your Python tools are up to date, it is easy to install:

```
python -m pip install SimpleGUICS2Pygame --user --upgrade
```

- Online HTML **documentation**: https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.io/

  - **Installation**: https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation
- **Sources**: https://bitbucket.org/OPiMedia/simpleguics2pygame

In your code, replace the import command

```
import simplegui
```

by

```
try:
    import simplegui
except ImportError:
    import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui
```

and your code run in CodeSkulptor **and** in standard Python (2 **and** 3) with this package.

Note that:

- [SimpleGUITk](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleGUITk/1.1.3) is an **other** implementation, using Tkinter and some others packages. It is really less complete and not updated. However it works for some programs.
- [simplegui](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplegui/0.1.1) is a Python package which has the same name as SimpleGUI of CodeSkulptor, but it is totally **something else**.

Comment: Works fine. I tried to write a script for the solution from shuvrow. But, on my Ubuntu 13.10 I always got an error by running python game.py: raise IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name)
After trying everything I switched to your solution, which is perfect. Good save me couple hours of my life taking your solution straight away.

Comment: I'm trying to install your package in Ubuntu. I've installed pip, but on running the command `>>> pip install SimpleGUICS2Pygame`, I get this error- `error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SimpleGUICS2Pygame': Permission denied`.
Any help on what's going wrong?

Comment: @Manish, you must use admin access. Try
`sudo [your command]`

Comment: Had already tried that. Got a bunch of error messages. Last two were: `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/BoxBlur.o: No such file or directory` and 
`error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1`.

The Pillow-Master folder is in my downloads folder. Do I need to move the pillow-master folder to somewhere else? But the installation instructions said nothing of that sort.

Comment: @Manish, SimpleGUICS2Pygame **don't** use Pillow!

Comment: I added precision in documentation: https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#installation

Comment: `pip install SimpleGUICS2Pygame` worked for me but `import  SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame` errored

Comment: user5570 import failed or it succeed and error come after?

Use ``import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui``

Comment: I am able to import and run programs using SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame, but the output still isn't working like the programs in codeskulptor.  Particularly the console print statements aren't displaying.  I am running on Mac OS 10.9.  Is this module (and installation instructions) compatible with Mac OS 10.9?

Comment: Alf47, With CodeSkulptor the output depend on your browser and your OS. So the difference with SimpleGUICS2Pygame is normal.

To see console output you must run your program from a console.

And yes, you can use SimpleGUICS2Pygame with Mac OS, normally no matter the version.

Answer (score 5):

I just installed simpleguitk to enable simplegui on my os. I am using linuxmint 15.
Steps are:

First download simpleguitk from this link [simpleguitk](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleGUITk).
In order to work with simplegui perfectly you have to install these packages

Pillow in order to use images.
Pygame for sound support
matplotlib for SimplePlot support.

1. You can install Pygame by suing this command :

   ```
    sudo apt-get install python-pygame
   ```
2. You can install matplotlib by using this command :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
   ```
3. To install  Pillow , download zip file from this link [Pillow](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow)

   Unzip it and change directory to Pillow. Then use this command  
   python setup.py install (assuming you've already installed python.h  or you can install it using

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python.h
   ```
4. Finally you have to install simpleguitk . Before installing it i suggest you to install this module setuptools.

   you can install setuptools using this command :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
   ```

   Now Extract simpleguitk on your home directory. Then change directory to simpleguitk folder.

   After that use this command :

   ```
   python setup.py install
   ```

Type `python` on terminal

Import simpleguitk as simplegui

Answer (score 1):

SimpleGUITk can be used in Python 3.

The Problem is simplegui.py

Just install SimpleGUITk as described in the README of the package.

Then modify the simplegui.py file in the python33 folder with an text-editor.

In the file are some calls for Tkinter.
Just replace **T**kinter with **t**kinter
and everything is fine and the example in the readme runs without errors.

(I also make a Coursera course. 
But the SimpleGUI module is not the simplegui used in CodeSkulptor.
Sorry, so you can't write programs for CodeSkulptor in IDLE with this lib)

Answer (score 1):

## Note: Steps is for windows

The replacement for simplegui is SimpleGUICS2Pygame.

Steps to install:
-
 Step 1: Install Python 2.7 and Simpleguics2Pygame from : https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/SimpleGUICS2Pygame/SimpleGUICS2Pygame-01.08.00.tar.gz#md5=e4a18fe83e4a64c6222bfb71349be31e

  Step 2: Extract it to a location (Lets call it somewhere)

 Step 3: Open command prompt as administrator and change directory using the command 
 cd somewhere/SimpleGUICS2Pygame-01.08.00.

Step 4: Run the command setup.py install

SimpleGUICS2Pygame is now installed and can now be accessed using the following code instead of `import simplegui`:

```
try:
    import simplegui
except ImportError:
    import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui
```

Comment: See the doc:
https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#complete-installation-on-window-in-few-steps

Comment: The install via pip does not seem sufficient. I got pygame and matplotlib to install fine via pip on windows, but i still got error during import on  SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame. I had to use the source and import the actual source file

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any information on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplegui/0.1.0) about which versions of Python simpleGUI supports. You can just try running it with Python 3 and see what happens. If it doesn't work, try using the 2to3 tools: http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Note that simpleGUI is based on Tkinter. I would recommend learning a full GUI toolkit like Tkinter, wxPython or PySide rather than a derivative.

Comment: SimpleGUI is **not**  based on Tkinter. It is a specific CodeSkulptor module written in JavaScript.

The Tkinter version is SimpleGUITk.

Comment: @OPi According to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplegui/0.1.1, "simplegui is a simplified GUI generator using Tkinter". There is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleGUITk/1.1.3, which I guess is what you are referring to.

Comment: Oh! Yes, OK Mike.
Note that this simplegui module *has nothing to do with* the SimpleGUI of CodeSkulptor (and with SimpleGUITk and SimpleGUICS2Pygame).