# Import simplegui error in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to install the simplegui module in pycharm. But, i am unable to install the module and getting the erroras Non-zero code exit. Please let me know how to solve it.

Shows solution as below:
Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Python34\python.exe'.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got stuck. If you're meaning the simplegui in [this coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/course/interactivepython), this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387770/how-to-integrate-simplegui-with-python-2-7-and-3-0-shell) may help.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I got exactly what i want. Much appreciated your help.

Comment: One more thing, I am unable to access the attributes of SimpleGUICS2Pygame. I am trying to develop a frame using SimpleGUICS2Pygame module. Below is code and it shows error. Kindly  help me. Code : frame = simplegui.create_frame("Pong",WIDTH,HEIGHT) .... It shows error   File "C:/Users/tspeed/PycharmProjects/sample1/sampel.py", line 125, in <module>
    frame = simplegui.create_frame("Pong",WIDTH,HEIGHT)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'create_frame'

Comment: The modules on Codeskulptor and on your machine(from pypi) are different. For detailed info, please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782976/module-object-has-no-attribute-create-frame).