# how to use codeskulptor in IDLE python 2.7 without having an error

Tags: python-2.7, codeskulptor

I followed the steps in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26194747/codeskulptor-simplegui-module-for-python-2-7 ,
I was looking to run an example code but i have got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/exemples/simpleGUI_exeple.py", line 4, in <module>
import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleGUICS2Pygame as simplegui
ImportError: No module named simpleGUICS2Pygame
```

what advice could you give me to fix that ? Thx in advance

Comment: you do not have the required module or it is not available in the namespace

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19612310/2443142). It provides the easiest solution to your problem. It contains the link to the guide to install the required module on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The process of installing pip, matplotlib and pygame seems insufficient on windows to resolve the error. For me, what I had to do on top of the documented install approach is to:

1. Go to: https://bitbucket.org/OPiMedia/simpleguics2pygame/downloads
2. Select the first item "Download Repository". It will download a zip file.
3. Open the downloaded zip file. Open the contained folder OPiMedia...
4. There is a SimpleGUICS2Pygame folder under that OPiMedia folder. Copy that into your python source code folder.

This will resolve the error.