# Convert Code from CodeSkulptor to PyCharm

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, codeskulptor

I am learning python from coursera. They are using CodeSkulptor(http://www.codeskulptor.org/) as IDE.
I want to write the same program in Pycharm.
I am unaware of inbuilt GUI packages in PyCharm(Python 2.7).
I want to convert below code. Please provide me some useful URL's/Important info.

Here is my code:

```
   # define event handlers for control panel
def foo():print "hello world!!!"


# create frame
f = simplegui.create_frame("Guess The Number",300,300)
f.add_button("Range [0,100)", foo, 150)
f.add_button("Range [0,1000)", foo, 150)
f.add_input("Enter a guess", foo, 150)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate SimpleGUI with Python 2.7 and 3.0 shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387770/how-to-integrate-simplegui-with-python-2-7-and-3-0-shell)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the documentation here

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleGUITk

Instead of

```
import simplegui
```

you should use

```
import simpleguitk as simplegui
```

Reference: [How to integrate SimpleGUI with Python 2.7 and 3.0 shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387770/how-to-integrate-simplegui-with-python-2-7-and-3-0-shell)

Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387770/how-to-integrate-simplegui-with-python-2-7-and-3-0-shell/19612310#19612310) also

Comment: Prefer my [SimpleGUICS2Pygame](https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.org/) package.
It is more complete.
See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19612310/1333666).